# How to add ga4 analytics for android projects?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-analytics

I have created two properties in Ga4. How to link those two properties to androidstudio so that when we use an android application, the same data should reflect in both properties dashboard. This is a shopping application. My database is firebase.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

to Google analytics to you Android Studio project you need to put the following in your code:

```
dependencies {
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')

    // Declare the dependency for the Analytics library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

this will declare the dependency for the Analytics Android library in your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle).

after that you need to Declare the com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics object at the top of your activity:

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
```

and at last you need to Initialize it in the onCreate() method:

```
// Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

to know more about how to sett the user properties you can check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=android) that could help you do it